# systemd-timesyncd: how to check and set network time synchronization interval?

Tags: ntp, systemd

I see only one event of time synchronization in log. It occurs at boot:

> systemd-timesyncd[690]: Synchronized to time server 188.112.42.5:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).

How to force periodic time updates? How to check what is the current interval?
I don't see anything interesting in `timesyncd.conf`?

Answer (score 3):

You can control the interval which this polls the NTP servers through these properties in the `systemd-timesyncd` config file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`:

> ```
>    PollIntervalMinSec=, PollIntervalMaxSec=
>
>    The minimum and maximum poll intervals for NTP messages. Each setting takes a time 
>    value (in seconds). PollIntervalMinSec= must not be smaller than 16 seconds. 
>    PollIntervalMaxSec= must be larger than PollIntervalMinSec=. PollIntervalMinSec= 
>    defaults to 32 seconds, and PollIntervalMaxSec= defaults to 2048 seconds.
> ```

The above appears to have been added in late 2017 - [timesync: make poll interval configurable #7268](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7268).

#### References

- [systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html)

Answer (score 1):

[systemd-timesyncd is a SNTP client that does a simple time set.](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-May/019537.html) This is specifically not a full NTP implementation, so it cannot estimate error and show performance over time.

Install chrony or ntpd, as you want constant slew to correct drift. Set it to use your internal NTP servers.